# How to create Android interstitial ads?

Tags: android, admob

I tried things from many blogs but none gave a step-by-step solution. Should I edit something on the AdMob site? I created the site from the ad sit/app option under the Sites & Apps tab.

I used this code:

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "MyAdMobID");
// Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
interstitial.setAdListener(this);
// Create ad request
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
// Begin loading your interstitial      
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
adRequest.setTesting(true);
```

Comment: Assuming "MyAdMobId" is replaced with your actual id, and you're testing in an emulator, this should work. What are you seeing in the logs? (Note that AdMob requires you to be whitelisted to serve network interstitials)

Comment: Nothing in the log, but how can I know if i'm whitelisted  to serve network interstitials?

Comment: You're likely not whitelisted.  AdMob only offers network interstiitals to a select few (see [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/advanced#overview)).  Unless you're whitelisted, you can only get the test interstitial, or a house interstitial if you set up an interstitial house ad campaign.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the last Android framework, I figured out that I need to call the load() function each time the ad is closed.

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.app.Activity;

class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdListener {
  private InterstitialAd adView;  // The ad
  private Handler mHandler;       // Handler to display the ad on the UI thread
  private Runnable displayAd;     // Code to execute to perform this operation

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    adView = new InterstitialAd(mContext);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX");
    adView.setAdListener(this);
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    displayAd = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {  
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
          public void run() { 
            if (adView.isLoaded()) {
              adView.show();
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
    loadAd();
  }

  @Override
  public void onAdClosed() {
    loadAd(); // Need to reload the Ad when it is closed.
  }

  void loadAd() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
   .build();

    // Load the adView object witht he request
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

  //Call displayInterstitial() once you are ready to display the ad.
  public void displayInterstitial() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(displayAd, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `loadAd` in the `onAdClosed`. This what you can be ready to display another ad.

Comment: which library ur using at present

Comment: Sorry I'm not programming on Android anymore.

Answer (score 11):

Unlike banners, insterstitial ads don't automatically show once their loaded.  You'll have to listen for AdMob's `onReceiveAd()` callback, and inside that callback, call `interstital.show()` to show your interstitial.

```
public YourActivity extends Activity implements AdListener {
  ...

  @Override
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
    Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
    if (ad == interstitial) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }
}
```

Check out a code example [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/doubleclick/#interstitials).  This example will show the interstitial as soon as it is received.  Alternatively, you may want to wait until a proper time to show the interstitial, such as at the end of a game level, and you could check `interstitial.isReady()` to see if you can show the interstitial.

Answer (score 6):

You cant implement AdListener anymore, I used it this way:

```
final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
});
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);
```

Place your own ID in strings.xml named interstitial_ad_unit_id, or replace

```
getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id)
```

with your ID.

Comment: Showing ads unexpectedly like this is very bad, and you may be blocked by Google. You better use `if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) mInterstitialAd.show();` somewhere else outside the `onAdLoaded()` callback where there would be no accidental clicks. See this: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6213019?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

I think this example code will help you out.

[How to Add AdMob Interstitial Ads in Your Android Apps](http://jmsliu.com/828/how-to-add-admob-interstitial-ads-in-your-android-apps.html)

In this example, it shows you the whole source code. And it also provides some solutions for common errors. For example, onFailedToReceiveAd error solution and no ad returned solution. You can also download the source code from there.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the `interstitial.isReady()` method is no longer supported. This is the correct method:

```
if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
    interstitial.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this function on app's opening:

```
InterstitialAd interstitial;

public void AdMob() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("YOUR_TEST_DEVICE_ID").build();
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("YOUR_AD_ID");
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            //Ads loaded
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            //Ads closed
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            //Ads couldn't loaded
        }
    });
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Then you can show ads:

```
if (interstitial.isLoaded()){
interstitial.show();
}
```

You should prepare ads before showing it. These took 3-5 seconds depending internet speed of device.

Answer (score 0):

adding banner and interstitial ads:

```
  AdView mAdView;
        InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
        ProgressDialog pd;

        void showAds(){
            if(interstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
        }
        public void initAds(){
            mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

            interstitialAd=new InterstitialAd(this);
            interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.inetial3));
            AdRequest adRequest1=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest1);
        }
```

and in XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in MainActivity.java

```
 private InterstitialAd interstitial; 

 // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK 
        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id)); 
        AdRequest adIRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); 

        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad Activity 
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this); 

        // Insert the Ad Unit ID 
       //add admob_interstitial_id unit id in string file 
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id)); 

        // Interstitial Ad load Request 
        interstitial.loadAd(adIRequest); 

        // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener 
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener()  
{ 
            public void onAdLoaded() 
            { 
                // Call displayInterstitial() function when the Ad loads 
                displayInterstitial(); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 

    public void displayInterstitial() 
    { 
        // If Interstitial Ads are loaded then show else show nothing. 
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) { 
            interstitial.show(); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;`

```
  //To load InterstitialAd ads

//app_id for test ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713


//full_id for test ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712

MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.app_id)); 
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.full_id));

mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {


@Override

public void onAdClosed() {

// Load the next interstitial

mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

}

});

//To show ads
 if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
 mInterstitialAd.show();
 } else {
Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
  }
```