# Adapting AdMob banner size to screen size

Tags: android, admob

I'm really struggling to find a solution to adapt the size of the banner to the device. I have a Samsung tablet 8" and a htc phone.

There is one app (radio) that is exactly doing what I need.

Tablet:

[image]

Phone:

[image]

The width on the tablet is almost twice the one on the phone. Same with the font.

I read https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/banner but I can't find the right solution.

I tried:

```
    AdView mAdView;
    mAdView = (AdView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bac_adView);
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and I get the error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size can only be set once on AdView.

But I'm not even sure this is the right way of doing.

Any pointers to some code would be great!

Comment: Admob has a fixed size and you wont be able to expand or compress it

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: Please follow my answer @narb

Comment: @AnuragAggarwal it sounds like narb just wants to use SMART_BANNER...an interstitial is completely different.  narb, have you tried setting the size in your layout xml instead of in your code?

Comment: yes. when you size the adview to a high number (like 400x300 dp) the banner stays the same.

Comment: thats what I am saying ads dimes are fixed for each resolution , you wont be able to expand and compress it .

Comment: there must be another solution!?

Comment: @narb I didn't mean setting height/width, I meant setting the adSize attribute to SMART-BANNER in the xml instead of the code

Comment: you were right. Many thanks!

Comment: you should have made the answer so to get the credit. you have too many points anyway :)

Comment: @narb haha! It was more of a suggestion, I didn't really know if it would solve it. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add AdView to your layout file in which you want to show banner.
Use smart banner size attribute.

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_id">
```

Now load the adView

```
AdView mAdView;
    mAdView = (AdView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bac_adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") 
            .build(); 
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Now your parent layout is RelativeLayout then use alignparentbottom attribute attribute in adview to fix the add at bottom of layout.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This will look more cleaner.

Comment: The SMART_BANNER is the trick. I don't use alignParentBottom because the banner is on top. Thanks.

Comment: Also for future take a look at native ads.

Comment: I just watch the google video. Interesting, this time I wanted a simple banner but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

AdView has a fixed size and you wont be able to expand or compress it . You need to display interstitial Ads which expands upto screen size of device

[How to create android Ad Interstitial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106322/how-to-create-android-ad-interstitial)

Comment: like Lewis says. interstitial is too intrusive. I'd like to keep a banner like solution,