# How to integrate Admob with Webview

Tags: java, webview, admob

i am a php/web/mysql/css/js developer and new to both, java and android. My first webview works like a charm, but i canot figure out why my admob is not working at all. i tried several tutorials from here and from the www so far, but without success. i am sure any of you geeks will find the issue immediately, so thank in advance. Will add the relevant code to this topic below, please let me know what is wrong here on my side.
If you need further sources, i can add it here as well.

thats what i have so far:

MainActivity

```
package smartmedia.de.mywebviewapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import static smartmedia.de.mywebviewapp.AnalyticsWebInterface.TAG;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyTtsTalker(this), "MyTtsTalker");
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new AnalyticsWebInterface(this), TAG);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack())
        {
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: your adView banner is visible at the bottom of the page or the complete space is taken by the webview  only? or the ad is not loading? please elaborate on this.

Comment: i am currently trying to display ANY ad, i havent spent any time in positioning and choosing a type of ad. Its not showing up at all. Currently i would prefer some full screen ads splashing over my webview and start from there. Webview is taking the entire space, i have no idea how to z-align(?!) the ad and the webview? maybe its displayed behind my webview? Sorry, i am completely new to android / java.

Comment: the issue is with the hierarchy that you are using in your xml, the banner is hiding behind your webview and hence it is not showing up. change the parent RelativeLayout to LinearLayout and give it attribute "android:orientation:vertical" for full screen ad you need to implement interstitial ad.  Go for this link to get familiar with fullscreen ads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106322/how-to-create-android-interstitial-ads

Comment: still nothing - i am testing with "Run\Run Main Activity".

Comment: i just updated the above which now gives me at least a small white area at the bottom of the screen with 50dp height, but still not showing any ads. But its a step! Thanks so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/footer_ad_id"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
<!--
   In the above adView, change height from wrap_content to some particular 
   size, 30dp, for example to see if you get the desired layout. 
   Even if the ad doesn't load, you know the layout is right because there
   will be a black color where the ad should load.
-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this results in a small white border at the bottom showing nothing, except a white background.

Comment: are you using a test banner id for the ad?

Comment: no id yet, i had code with an id to test out before, but no idea where and how to add it yet.

Comment: see that's why. You see without any ads to load, the ad adView with a height and width of wrap_content takes 0 as size. try specifying something for height, like 25dp maybe.

Comment: @SaschaGrindau I've changed the answer accordingly, do check and let me know.

Comment: with this i am getting a red box containing the following string: "Requiered XML attribute "adsize" was missing."

Comment: Sorry about that, my bad. I fixed that and updated the answer. Check now.

Comment: i added adUnitId and adSize and now i am having a black bar there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179468/discussion-between-jacob-celestine-and-sascha-grindau).

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to change your xml file like below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/footer_ad_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: -> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
namespace declaration is never used and its not shwoing any ad when starting.